# Two HTML elements with background color that "ends" a little after the start of second element

Tags: html, css

I have two div elements and a background color. What I want to achieve is having the background color 'end' a little bit after the point where the second element starts. Like this:

[image: 1]

```
    <div>
   <div style="background-color:red;">
      <div class="container">
         Element 1
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="background-color:white;">
      <div class="container">
         Element 2
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If I understand correctly, what I want to change here is the 'offset' of the background color. But is that even possible and how could I do it?

Comment: How about using `translateY()` to move element2?

Comment: @Shuo I think that will work, I will play around with it and see if that solves it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) to draw a background with the color and the height you want.

The Red background is set on the parent of the elements, not on each element, so that we can tune it as we want.

See this example:

```css
#main {
  border: thin solid Black;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, Red 35%, transparent 35%);
  
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  border: thin solid Black;
  background: White;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">Element 1</div>
    <div class="container">Element 2</div>
</div>
```